# Designating databases to certain CPUs

Tags: sql-server, optimization

SQL Server 2012.
AlwaysOn
Cluster with two nodes, each has 4 cores

We are consolidating SQL server instances and moving bunch of databases from various locations to a single cluster which has two instances, 4 cores each.
There are "more" and "less" important databases which are going to be mixed at the same location. Is there a way to make queries from a database to use only certain core on the host?

Example:

We have 10 databases named A1-A10.
Can we make queries from 6 "less" important databases A1-A6 to use only one core (always the same core 0) , and leave queries from other 4 "more" important databases A7-A10  to use rest of the cores (in this case 1-3).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make queries from a database to use only certain core on the host?

One way is to use query hint `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)`.

The problem with above apporach is that you have to *hint everything* that you don’t want to be limited by the server-wide setting, or use 0 (i.e. unlimited) for the server-wide setting and hint everything that you *do* want to be limited.

> Can we make queries from 6 "less" important databases A1-A6 to use only one core (always the same core 0) , and leave queries from other 4 "more" important databases A7-A10 to use rest of the cores (in this case 1-3).

A better way is to use **Resoruce Governor**. It is available only in Enterprise Edition (Dev edition as well).

Note: ***Make sure you do proper testing before implementing directly in PROD*** as I have seen really bad cases where without understanding, Resource Governor is implemented and things go horribly wrong.

If you are running on Enterprise Edition then you can create

- CREATE RESOURCE POOL -- here you can specify min and max CPU allowance. Also by using `AFFINITY SCHEDULER`, you can bind specific schedulers to your Pool.
- CREATE WORKLOAD GROUP USING RESOURCE POOL. -- Here you can specify `max_dop=1`. 
  This MAXDOP setting overrides the server-wide setting and any query hints.

Refer to : [Resource Governor in SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj573256) whitepaper for more details.

Aaron Bertrand has explained very nicely at : [SQL Server 2012 Resource Governor Enhancement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/20849/8783)

Comment: You could also create two separate instances, one instance could then be limited to operate on a single CPU, the other instance on the other 3 CPUs, with the databases separated by instance accordingly

Comment: Good point @MaxVernon .. Agree with you if that is Feasible for OP. Also, it will add licensing cost as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Soft-NUMA.  Here's a Perfmon screen shot from a 4-CPU VM I set up to test using your settings, 2 soft NUMA nodes, 1 CPU to Node 0, 3 CPUs to Node 1.  I'm running a CPU intensive query for 20 seconds on node 0, and then the same query on node 2.  You can see the CPU activity swap over:

[image]

I'm running the query via sqlcmd and connecting using the tcp ports I specified, eg

```
REM Run CPU intensive query with 20 second timeout
sqlcmd -S WIN-xxxx,2001 -ic:\temp\temp.sql -dtempdb -t 20
sqlcmd -S WIN-xxxx,2002 -ic:\temp\temp.sql -dtempdb -t 20
```

The respective CPU masks would be 0x01 (or 1) for Node 0, and 0x0e (or 14) for Node 1.  I followed the registry instructions from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345357(v=sql.110).aspx) and port mapping from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07727642-0266-4cbc-8c55-3c367e4458ca(v=sql.110)).  I did not need to use ALTER SERVER CONFIGURATION.  Jonathan Kehayias' [article](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/sql-server-and-soft-numa/) was also invaluable reading.

A powerful technique in SQL Server consolidation.

HTH